# Raspberry Pi - GPIO setup - States Switched

Tags: python, pi-2, relay

I am currently using Raspberry PI to to control a 2 switch relay. I am testing it with the most basic code just switching one of them on and off. Before I connect it to something live I want to make sure I have this figured out as it seems there is something weird going on. It seems like my states are the wrong way around.

Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)
```

Now the issue is with the last line. The moment I use that command my GPIO pin activates however, on all tutorials this is not the case.

The next part is if I call:

```
 GPIO.output(5,0)
```

I would expect it to turn off however I need to use:

```
GPIO.output(5,1)
```

To power it off. To be honest it doesn't make much of a difference however I don't like the fact that it is on by default. Apart from that it works as expected. Tested with LEDs and had the same effect.

I am really new so might be missing something simple. Any help would greatly be appropriated.

Answer (score 2):

Some relays are active high (switch on with a high input) and some relays are active low.

Whether LEDs light when a GPIO is set high or low depends on how you wire them.

If you have `GPIO - resistor - aLEDc - Ground` the LED will light with a high GPIO and go off with a low GPIO.

If you have `GPIO - resistor - cLEDa - 3V3` the LED will light with a low GPIO and go off with a high GPIO.

The `a` (anode) and `c` (cathode) either side of `LED` indicates their orientation.